# How to use LIKE statement with multiple values from another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, compare, sql-like

I want to select all records where field contains values from another field. How do I do that? Here is a code that I am trying.

```
select field1 , field2, field3 
from table1
where field1 like '%'+(select distinct field4 from table2)+'%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do your like as a join condition:

```
select field1 , field2, field3 
from table1
join (select distinct field4 from table2) x
  on field1 like '%'+field4+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the original structure of your query, you can do:

```
select field1, field2, field3 
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2
              where t1.field1 like '%' + field4 + '%'
             );
```

The advantage of this method is that it will not duplicate records in `table1`.  For instance, if there are two rows in `table2` with the values `'a'` and `'b'` respectively and one row in `table1` with the value `'ab'`, then this method will only return the row from table1 once.