# SQL ending in multiple values

Tags: sql

Below line from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324012/sql-how-to-select-words-with-certain-values-at-the-end-of-word) shows how to match based upon end characters.

```
select * from table where Name like '%es'
```

How could I modify the code if I want to match with multiple values. For example I have another table `T2` that has column `C1` and I want all values from column `Name` that end in values from column `C1`

if I want to find all Names that are in `C1`, I would use

```
 select * from table where Name in (select C1 from T2)
```

on a similar lines I want something like below. It is a pseudo code

```
  select * from table where Name like (select '%C1' from T2)
```

Column `C1` and `Name` have thousands of values in them

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LIKE statement with multiple values from another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181640/how-to-use-like-statement-with-multiple-values-from-another-field)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `exists` and subquery makes `LIKE` column value by `+` or `||`  depend on your DBMS.

```
select * 
from table t1
where exists(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM T2 
   WHERE t1.Name LIKE '%' + T2.C1
)
```

or

```
select * 
from table t1
where exists(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM T2 
   WHERE t1.Name LIKE '%' || T2.C1
)
```

Here is a mysql sample.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
   Name varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('cat hat');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('cat aaa');

CREATE TABLE T2(
   C1 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('cat');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * 
from  t1
where exists(
   SELECT C1 
   FROM t2
   WHERE t1.Name LIKE '%' || T2.C1
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/274529/2/0)**:

```
|    Name |
|---------|
| cat hat |
| cat aaa |
```

Comment: thanks. What is the purpose of `SELECT 1 
   FROM T2 
`?

Comment: The `EXISTS` operator is used to test for the existence of any record in a subquery. `select 1` mean get the value from the condition, you can also use `SELECT * FROM T2 ` depend on you

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we need to get `column1`, `column2` from `tablename`, in which `column2` *ends* with either `A` or `B` or `C`:

Then we can simply write below query:`

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM tablename
WHERE RIGHT(column2,1) in ('A','B','C');
```